# Deleting Image from a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a ViewPager to show my Images.

These Images are sent as a List from One Activity to another & then I show them in the ViewPager.

But the Issue is that if I click on a Delete Button them the Image is Deleted & Removed from the List but it still show on the Next Image.

e.g. 1st Image's height is fullscreen > I delete it, viewpager moves to next Image, this image has a height of 350 then the background above & below 350 shows the old Image...

Also, I get a IndexOutOfBoundsExceptiom when I try to delete the 2nd Last Item...

Heres my Code -

```
public class ImageViewer extends AppCompatActivity {

public int position;
private ArrayList<String> list;
private HackyViewPager pager;
private ImagePagerAdapter ipa;
private List<PhotoView> photoViewList;
private HelperMethods helperMethods;
private static boolean sendResult = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.img);

    sendResult = false;
    helperMethods = new HelperMethods(ImageViewer.this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
    list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list");

    pager = (HackyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    photoViewList = new ArrayList<PhotoView>();

    for(int val = 0; val < list.size(); val++) {
        PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(this);
        photoView.setZoomable(true);

        Glide.with(ImageViewer.this)
            .load(new File(list.get(val)))
            .into(photoView);

        photoViewList.add(photoView);
    }

    ipa = new ImagePagerAdapter(photoViewList);
    pager.setAdapter(ipa);
    pager.setCurrentItem(position);

    FloatingActionButton dlt = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.dlt);
    dlt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageViewer.this);

                builder.setMessage("Sure to Delete this Image?")
                    .setNegativeButton("Nope", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })

                    .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            getFilePos().delete();
                            ipa.remove(pager.getCurrentItem());

                            Toast.makeText(ImageViewer.this, "Image Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                        }
                    });
                builder.create()
                    .show();

            }
        });
}


public File getFilePos() {
    return new File(list.get(pager.getCurrentItem()));
}




    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }




static class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<PhotoView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<PhotoView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    void remove(int pos) {
        images.remove(pos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I didn't go through all the code, but when you delete the item, do you also delete it from `photoViewList`? As I said, I didn't study the code, but I think you should remove it from the list as well to avoid OutOfBounds exception.

Comment: @LieForBananas I delete via the List in the Adapter, so probably both are same I guess 

Comment: Didn't see that :) but it removes just the View doesn't it? I'm not sure if it's equivalent to removing item from the list. The only reason I think you may have for OutOfBounds exception is because of that.

Comment: @LieForBananas I'll try & report :)

Comment: @LieForBananas Managed to Delete the Image proprrly, but still getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException on last & second last item :(

Comment: Try to put `ipa.remove(pager.getCurrentItem());` before `getFilePos().delete();`, basically swap them.

Answer (score 0):

After deletion of image from list you must call the

> notifyitemremoved();

on method remove on adapter.

Comment: I'm already calling notifyDataSetChanged(); after removin image, pls check the Adapter method 'remove()'

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

you have to set the adapter to viewpager again, then it will refresh the content.

**removeView(int pos) in my PagerAdaper**

```java
public void removeView(int index) {
       imageFileNames.remove(index);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

***wherever I am removing the file I have to do like this***

```java
imagePagerAdapter.removeView(currentPosition);
viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);
```

**EDIT:**

> This below method is effective, you can apply the below one.

```java
public void updateView(int pos){
      viewPager.setAdapter(null);
      imagePagerAdapter =new ImagePagerAdapter(YOUR_CONTEXT,YOUR_CONTENT);
      viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}
```

> replace YOUR_CONTEXT with your context and your content with your content name i.e. updated list or something.

Comment: setting the Adapter again on every delete action is highly not recommended, I migrated to ViewPager2 which is based on RecyclerView and it handles it quite better with ‘notifyItemRemoved()’.